# Can we create a share dialog box pointing to a group so that the url or information will be shared to a group directly?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I'm trying to share a link and message directly to a group.  When I try to do this using a link like https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?display=page&u=https://google.com this shares to my timeline, not to a group.

Is there a way to do this?  Thank you.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?display=page&u=https://google.com

I've also tried using the below qualifiers with no luck so far.
&userid=
&defaultgroupid=
&audience=group
&audience_targets=
&audience_group=

I desire to share directly to a group.
This link shares to my timeline instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) and the [Send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) have a `to` parameter to specify a recipient upfront.

And while the documentation for the Feed dialog explicitly says,

> `to`: The ID of the profile that this story will be published to. If this is unspecified, it defaults to the value of from. The ID must be a friend who also uses your app.

and for the Send dialog

> A user ID of a recipient.

it currently seems to work with both of them, to specify the Id of a *group* the user is a member of instead - I tested both, and both times the group I specified got pre-filled into the “To” / “Recipient” field of the dialog.

---

But since this does contrast what the documentation states, don’t be too surprised if it should stop working this way one day.

Answer (score 0):

The user selects where to he wants to share, there are no options to pre-select "Share in a Group" in the dialog itself.